# Apache server not Listening for localhost?

Tags: apache-http-server

I use Apache 2.4 on my Linode server. Everything is OK 3 days ago, but now when i visit http://127.0.0.1/ from my linode server,the server access log showed that i visit it from the public ip

```
106.184.*.* - - [09/Feb/2017:00:56:28 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

It should be:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2017:00:56:28 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

I have install a l2tp server on my Linode server 3 days ago, it may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is the iptables problem.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```